# selectedvalue of combobox in datagrid not getting set - silverlight mvvm model

Tags: silverlight

Below is the XAML snippet for my combo-box in a datagrid.

```
<data:DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="Entry Mode">
                    <data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=EntryModeCombo,Mode=TwoWay}"    DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Id" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=selectedEntryMode,Mode=TwoWay}" ></ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </data:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Entrymode is an entity in the system and the Id and Name properties of this entity are used to set the DisplayMemberPath and SelectedValuePath of the combo.

```
public class A
{
 private ObservableCollection<EntryMode> _EntryModeCombo;
        public ObservableCollection<EntryMode> EntryModeCombo
        {
            get { return _EntryModeCombo; }
            set
            {
                _EntryModeCombo = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("EntryModeCombo");
            }
        }

 private string _selectedEntryMode;
        public string selectedEntryMode
        {
            get { return _selectedEntryMode; }
           set
            {
                _selectedEntryMode = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("selectedEntryMode");
           }
        }
}
```

In my viewModel, I am making an observable collection of the class A, and using that to bind a grid. All works well in the ADD mode, but in the edit mode, when I try to set the selected value of the combobox in the grid, it does not work. The population of the combo-box happens, but it remains unselected. Not sure why the selectedEntryMode property is getting set, but not affecting the combo selection in the grid.
Any suggestions will be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Managed to make it work with selectedItem instead of selectedValue...any insights on the selectedValue part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*SelectedValue* can only be used for getting value. not setting. use *SelectedItem* insted